# AutoLayout constraints break on iOS 9 and right to left language

Tags: objective-c, autolayout, interface-builder, ios9, right-to-left

I have an app that has iOS 8 as a development target and uses auto Layout from Interface Builder to position the views. all the UI is rendered correctly without any errors being thrown in the console output while running under iOS 8.

under iOS 9 and a left to right language the app also behaves as expected. but when I change the locale to a right to left language, the UI behaves unexpectedly also conflicting constraints errors are thrown in the console.

I'm suspecting the issue is related to Leading and trailing constraints but I can't find the correct way to fix it.

[image: Interface builder constraints]

> and here's the console output on iOS 9

```
 Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x15c5f2270 UILabel:0x15d80bd30'Buy'.centerX == CurrencyListSectionHeader:0x15d8b1550.centerX>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x15c740090 H:[UILabel:0x15d8858f0'Sell']-(20)-|   (Names: '|':CurrencyListSectionHeader:0x15d8b1550 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x15c7a0e50 H:[UILabel:0x15d80bd30'Buy']-(NSSpace(8))-[UILabel:0x15d8858f0'Sell']>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x15c79ebc0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' H:[CurrencyListSectionHeader:0x15d8b1550(375)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x15c7a0e50 H:[UILabel:0x15d80bd30'Buy']-(NSSpace(8))-[UILabel:0x15d8858f0'Sell']>
```

Comment: Having the same issue now ... I am assuming you upgraded to Xcode 7, how can you debug iOS 9 devices otherwise? Personally, I reverted to Xcode 6 ... It seems to obviously be an iOS bug, just need to find a good workaround

Comment: Hey, the behaviour above was actually occurring on a release version, the app was built using Xcode 6 and installed on iOS 9 device.

Don't waste your time trying to solve these issues using Xcode 6, just debug the app on Xcode 7 and it will all make sense.  I dropped support for iOS 7 as well, so my app now supports iOS 8, 9

Comment: Thanks, Ahmad. Unfortunately, iOS 9 upgrade is very painful for our app at the moment, and would rather avoid that. i must figure it out, I have a few ideas that might work.